# Subfigure captions of EPS file formats do not align with images in two-column paper

Tags: captions, subfloats, two-column, subcaption, eps

I have trouble getting EPS images aligned work properly in latex. First, my figures were rotated by 90 degrees in the pdf output. So I rotated them by using "angle=90". But I am using a two-column Layout and the subfigure captions do not align with the column width. Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\ioptwocol
\begin{figure}[]
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t!]{\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth,angle=90]{Im1.eps}
                \caption{}
                \label{}
        \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}[t!]{\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth,angle=90]{Im2.eps}
                \caption{}
                \label{}
        \end{subfigure}
\caption{Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.}
\label{fig:CT}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'd appreciate any help. Here is how the output looks like. Note the position of the circled captions wrt the column. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
%\ioptwocol
%\blindtext[0]
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t!]{\columnwidth}% use \columnwidth instead of \textwidth
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true, height=0.6\columnwidth,width=0.9\columnwidth,angle=0]{a.eps}
                \caption{}
                \label{}
        \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}[t!]{\columnwidth}
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true, height=0.6\columnwidth,width=0.9\columnwidth,angle=0]{a.eps}
                \caption{}
                \label{}
        \end{subfigure}
\caption{Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.Here is the caption.}
\label{fig:CT}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```